# Cannot use CURLOPT_INTERFACE

Tags: php, curl, centos, ip, cpanel

There is a cPanel (CentOs) server, and an additional IP address has been added.

but users cannot use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "eth0:cp1");
// OR
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "IP_ADDRESS");
```

I turned off the firewall, tried adding by WHM and /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/, reserving ips, adding A records to DNS Zone, and so on... but still it's not working.

After executing the cURL request, it just times out.

what kind of configuration are required before being able to use CURLOPT_INTERFACE?

Comment: Does the interface and address work outside of curl?  Can you remotely access a website on that interface from outside the network?  I was able to switch the interface on a cPanel server on CentOS w/ selinux without any issues from an unprivileged user running the curl script.

Comment: @drew010 So basically you just added the IP to cpanel and you could use without doing anything else? When I open IP addresses directly, they all redirect me to the same "IP/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi", so I guess it's okay

Comment: Yeah, nothing special needed, but I did have to bind that IP address to my router's WAN interface so it knew to accept traffic to the address.  If you can hit that IP externally and see a sys default webpage, then it sounds like the address is bound correctly and accepting traffic fine.  I passed `eth0:cp7` to curl and it worked fine.  Can you try with SELinux totally off?  I have it on but in permissive mode.

Comment: @drew010 I checked and SELinux config file and it's disabled by default (SELINUX=disabled).

Comment: Is this server behind any sort of router/firewall, or connected directly to the internet with WAN IP's getting assigned to the interfaces?

Comment: @drew010 It is directly connected AFAIK, I'm just re-installing the droplet now. because I changed too many things maybe I messed something up.

Comment: @drew010 I re-installed and did 4 things differently, not sure which one caused this, but now it's working (see my own answer below). Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

In case some one else has this issue,

I re-installed the Server and did 4 things differently:

1. Did not enable CPHulk
2. Used a random (invalid) DNS when finishing cpanel installation (My domain has managed DNS pointing to the IP)
3. When creating the new host in cPanel I did not check "Use the nameservers specified at the Domain’s Registrar"
4. I added the IPs (using WHM) after creating the host this time

I'm still not sure which one was causing the previous weird issue.

Basically I did nothing. `Install cPanel` > `Create Host (Create a New Account)` > `Add IP Addresses` (using WHM) > `Rebuild the IP Address Pool` > `Restart`